# Google Analytics - Connecting custom metrics to search term dimension using gtag

Tags: google-analytics, gtag.js

Looking for a gtag ninja who can help me resolve a small problem with search term data (internal searches) and custom dimensions.

A client has switched to using gtag. Before migrating we were able to view data from a custom metric in relation to each search term in a custom report. Since switching to gtag this data no longer appears.

The search terms are also recorded as events, this works fine and we can get the custom metric data no problem.

So I guess the question is how we can reconnect the custom metrics to the search term dimension? Anyone got any experience of this or suggestions of what might be wrong?

Comment: What was your code before that worked? Are you able to share the site?

Comment: Appreciate the reply and sorry for the delay getting back to you. 

Before we had a simple setup:

`ga('create', '@accountId', 'auto');  
ga('set', 'metric1', numSearchResult);  
ga('set', 'metric2', 1); // always 1  
ga("send",  
{  
hitType: "pageview",  
page: searchPageUrl,  
});`  

Metric 1 was the number of search results returned and metric 2 was the number of searches performed.

Comment: Now we are using:

`gtag('js', new Date());
gtag('config', gaCode,
{
'custom_map': {
'metric1': 'metric1',
'metric2': 'metric2'
}`

With the following event data:

`gtag('event', 'search', {
hitType: "pageview",
'search_term': 'testterm13',
'metric1': 12,
'metric2': 1,
page: '/en/se/search'
});`

This stores the query as an event along with the custom metrics (so we know those work) but the custom metrics don't appear in the search term report as they used to.